# Mongoose - insert object with array to mongo DB

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Mongo for the first time and I'm having difficulties with creating a document which has an array.
The object is passed to a nodejs server like so:

```
{
"customerid":"121212",
"name": "Zero 2679",
"email": "a@a.com",
"address": "bla bla bla",
"tokens":[{"ctoken":"123456"},{"ctoken":"1234567"}]
}
```

The code executes the following:

```
           var newCustomer = new Customer(
            {
              _id: request.body.customerid,
              name: request.body.name,
              email: request.body.email,
              address: request.body.address,
              tokens:request.body.tokens
             });
            newCustomer.save(function (err) {
              if (err) winston.log('error', err);
              // saved!
            })
```

The schema is configured like so:

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({

//  index: true => Tells mongo to index this paramater because it is used frequently. It makes querying faster
_id: {type: String, unique: true},  // unique customer ID

name: {type: String, default: '', required: true}, // Customer name

//email: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true},

address: { type: String, required: true },

toknes: [{ ctoken :{type: String} }]

}, {collection: 'customers'});
```

When I go and look at the object in the MongoDB, it looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "121212",
"email": "a@a.com",
"address": "bla bla bla",
"tokens": [],
"name": "Zero 2679",
"__v": 0
}
```

The tokens are missing and there's a '_v' value which I don't even have.

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: _v is from mongo, don't worry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your schema

`tokens: [{ ctoken : String }]`

`request.body.tokens` must be something like = `{ctoken: 'some string'}`

```
       var newCustomer = new Customer(
        {
          _id: request.body.customerid,
          name: request.body.name,
          email: request.body.email,
          address: request.body.address,
          tokens:[request.body.tokens]
         });
        newCustomer.save(function (err) {
          if (err) winston.log('error', err);
          // saved!
        })
```

and if the customer db documents contains data, then you should perform `push` operation

Comment: Tried this, still does not work. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: in schema there's a `toknes` field instead of `tokens`, do a `console.log(req.body.tokens)`

Comment: 4 , a typo, I can't believe it.

Comment: @p0k8_13, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema it should be:

```
tokens: [{ type: String }]
```

As ctoken is not a data type. The working schema is illustrated below:

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({
 _id: {type: String, unique: true}, 
 name: {type: String, default: '', required: true},
 email: {type: String, required: true},
 address: { type: String, required: true },
 tokens: [{ type: String }]
}, {collection: 'customers'});
```

Comment: Tried this, still does not work. Please take a look at my updated question.